# How to know, how many things is created in tkinter canvas?

Tags: python, tkinter, counting, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to figure out, how can we know how many times we create anything inside `canvas`. I had seen that `tkinter.canvas.create_<>` return some integer values, I think they say it `id` and that integer value is number of created things in `canvas`(Not exactly this but we can say this). If they are returning number then obviously they are counting it but isn't that available for us?

Is there any way to know, how many things is created in it?

**Idea :**
I think I have figured something:

1. Count by ourself, IDK how but by creating some function to create anything in canvas and while doing that count those.
2. Or as I already say, `canvas.create_<>` return integer value which tells how many things are created(id) use that.

I have read some articles about `canvas`, read official documentation, also look at the code of `canvas` but didn't figure out anything. Is my idea best, at the end or is there any other things to know how many things are created in `canvas`.

Comment: Are you looking for something like [`len(<tkinter.Canvas>.find_all())`](http://web.archive.org/web/20201108093851/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.find_all-method)

Comment: @TheLizzard Can this question/title be edited or is there anything that can be improved cuz I haven't found anything about it, so I have to ask question. I have found that there is answer about this things. If you can improve then you may edit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass "all" to the `find` method of the canvas to get a tuple of all identifiers. The length of that is the count of all items on the canvas.

```
items = canvas.find("all")
```

You can also use the `find_all` method:

```
items = canvas.find_all()
```

Comment: @Xitiz: I don't know what you mean by _"What is that (<>,?)"_.

Comment: @Xitiz: no, `canvas.find_all()` returns a tuple containing all of the ids for all of the objects on the canvas.

Comment: Can this question/title be edited or is there anything that can be improved cuz I haven't found anything about it, so I have to ask question. I have found that there is answer about this things. If you can improve then you may edit it. @Bryan